# Running Watcher at startup

Tags: boot, init.d

I need to monitor for changes across a folder and its sub-folders and am using [Watcher](https://github.com/splitbrain/Watcher) for this purpose.  No issues thus far.  However, I want to have the Watcher daemon run on reboot.  For staters I tried the following.

**/etc/init.d**

I created the following simple script here

```
#! /bin/bash
watcher.py start
```

with `watcher.py` located in the `/usr/local/bin` folder.  I then created a symlink from the `/etc/rc2.d` folder `ln -s /etc/init.d/watcher /etc/rc2.d/S99watcher` and rebooted.

Checking `watcher.py status` reported that it was not running.  So I modified my `init.d` script as follows

```
#! /bin/bash
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/watcher.py start
```

and rebooted. This time `watcher.py status` correctly reported Watcher as running.

The immediate problem may be solved but I still do not understand why.  Why is it that from an interactive shell prompt I can simply type `watcher.py start` to have the Watcher daemon started whilst at bootup I need to explicitly tell Python to run that script?

I generally get my shell & startup scripts working by dint of not giving up rather than any in-depth knowledge of how such things work.  I hope that someone here will be able to provide a more informed insight.

Comment: Obviously,  `$PATH` is not set yet on the moment the script is called, hence the need for absolute paths.

Comment: @JacobVlijm- thanks.The `s99watcher` symlink is intended to ensure that the script is called after all other serivices, e.g. MySQL, have started.  When does $PATH get set?  After everything in rc2.d has been run?

Comment: I don't think I am the specialist on this, but these two, I believe, shed some light on the subject: http://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/481685/path-issues-for-init-d-scripts-on-startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When is $PATH set?

About `/etc/profile`:

As we can read [here](http://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/):

> ...The `/etc/profile` file is not very different however it is used to
>   set system wide environmental variables on users shells. The variables
>   are sometimes the same ones that are in the `.bash_profile`, however
>   this file is used to set an initial `PATH` or `PS1` for all shell users of
>   the system.

and:

> In addition to the setting environmental items the `/etc/profile` will
>   execute the scripts within `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`

Which means that `$PATH` (for all users) is actually set *by* scripts in `/etc/profile.d`, as we can also conclude [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html).

Looking into my system, not all is exactly as described [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html), but the information is confirmed nevertheless.

A quick (textual) search in `/etc` on the string: `/usr/local/bin`, of which I know it is in my (global) `$PATH`, produces the file `/etc/environment`, which contains the line:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

These are exactly the directories in my `$PATH` (apart from the local ones).

The bottom line is that `$PATH` is not set *before* the scripts in `/etc/init.d` are run, but actually set *by* scripts in `etc/init.d`

#### What to do?

The answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/481685/path-issues-for-init-d-scripts-on-startup) suggest to set the `$PATH` variable at the top of the script. Looking (again) in my system, that is exactly what was done with e.g. my `/etc/init.d/saned` script:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Using absolute paths like you did will work as well of course.